# Regular expression for multiple occurances in python

Tags: python, regex

I need to parse lines having multiple language codes as below

```
008800002     Bruxelles-Nord$Br�ussel Nord$<deu>$Brussel Noord$<nld>
```

- `008800002` being a id
- `Bruxelles-Nord$Br�ussel Nord$` being name1
- `deu` being language one
- `$Brussel Noord$` being name two
- `nld` being language two.

SO, the idea is name and language can appear N number of times. I need to collect them all.
the language in `<>` is 3 characters in length (fixed)
and all names end with `$` sign.

I tried this one but it is not giving expected output.

```
x = re.compile('(?P<stop_id>\d{9})\s(?P<authority>[[\x00-\x7F]{3}|\s{3}])\s(?P<stop_name>.*)
    (?P<lang_code>(?:[<]\S{0,4}))',flags=re.UNICODE)
```

I have no idea how to get repeated elements.
It takes

`Bruxelles-Nord$Br�ussel Nord$<deu>$Brussel Noord$` as stop_name and `<nld>` as language.

Comment: You might want to fix encoding issues first. It's `Brüssel`, not `Br�ussel`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it in two steps. First separate ID from name/language pairs; then use `re.finditer` on the name/language section to iterate over the pairs and stuff them into a dict.

```
import re

line = u"008800002     Bruxelles-Nord$Br�ussel Nord$<deu>$Brussel Noord$<nld>"
m = re.search("(\d+)\s+(.*)", line, re.UNICODE)
id = m.group(1)
names = {}
for m in re.finditer("(.*?)<(.*?)>", m.group(2), re.UNICODE):
    names[m.group(2)] = m.group(1)
print id, names
```

Answer (score 2):

```
\b(\d+)\b\s*|(.*?)(?=<)<(.*?)>
```

Try this.Just grab the captures.see demo.

http://regex101.com/r/hS3dT7/4